# NULL value in AppSettings - Accessing config file from Class Library

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to read value from appSettings but getting `null` value in return. Also getting `null` value in `element` variable present in my class file. Below is my class file content.

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;

namespace SampleDLL
{
    public class Class1
    {
        private static string GetAppSetting(Configuration config, string key)
        {
            var testValue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key]; //Alternate option.
            var element = config.AppSettings.Settings[key];
            if (element == null) return string.Empty;
            var value = element.Value;
            return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? value : string.Empty;
        }

        public void GetDataAppConfig()
        {
            Configuration config = null;
            var exeConfigPath = GetType().Assembly.Location;
            try
            {
                config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(exeConfigPath);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                //handling exception here.
            }
            if (config != null)
            {
                var myValue = GetAppSetting(config, "myKey");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My app.config file is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="myKey" value="TestValue"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Reference to `System.Configuration` is present in my Class Library Project. I am calling `GetDataAppConfig` form from the one windows form present in another project of same solution.

**Edited**

I am using config file present in my Class Library Project.

[image]

My WinForm class is as below which I am using to call `GetDataAppConfig` present in class`Class1` of class library project.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using SampleDLL;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var class1 = new Class1();
            class1.GetDataAppConfig();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try use `AppSettingsSection` instead of a `NameValueCollection`. Like `config.GetSection("appSettings").Settings[key].Value;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read from App.config in a Class Library project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9871948/read-from-app-config-in-a-class-library-project)

Comment: @Liam I do not want to use config file present in client application.

Comment: Of course even if you do get this working, any config added to the clients application would override your own. Basically, don't do this, your just giving yourself a headache you could do without.

Comment: Also, possible duplicate of [Can a class library have an App.config file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817051/can-a-class-library-have-an-app-config-file)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're calling `OpenExeConfiguration()` with the wrong configuration file, by determining the configuration file using

```
var exeConfigPath = GetType().Assembly.Location;
```

You're actually using the path of the Class Library that defines your `Class1` type when you actually want to load the configuration of the current client referencing `Client1` (the WinForm app in your case).

Try this instead:

```
config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms134265(v=vs.110).aspx)

---

**Update:**

Since you want to embed the configuration file in your Class Library project, you'll have to follow the following steps:

- Change the file name from `App.Config` to something else (so that it won't collide with the client's configuration file).
- Change the `Build Action` of the file to `Content`
- Change `Copy to output directory` to `Copy always`

Then in your code:

```
try
{
    var configurationMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap
    {
        // assuming name of your file is "ClassiLibrary1.config"
        ExeConfigFilename = Path.Combine(exeConfigPath, "ClassLibrary1.config")
    };

    config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configurationMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
}
```

Comment: FYI, my config file is present in my class library project. I missed to mention the same. I have edited my question for this.

Comment: @ManojNaik Add the config to the calling application, not the class library. The class library is consumed by the calling application, this is the context, so the config should also be in the context of the consuming application

Comment: @haim770 I have used the solution suggested by you but still getting null. Just wanted to know , what Liam is suggesting is it correct ? If it is then is there any alternative for the same?

Comment: @ManojNaik, Of course he's correct. Client configuration should be your default. I assumed you have a very good reason why to embed the configuration in the class library.

Comment: @haim770 I want to keep my configuration settings specific to class library project. Also, I want to use that class library in diff application with diff values. Due to the same I am trying above scenario. If there is no solution to the above scenario then I have to find alternate any option for this.

Comment: @Liam and haim Thanks for your suggestions. Just wanted to know is there any option to close this Question?

Comment: @ManojNaik, Did you follow all the steps I described in the modified answer (including the rename)? Did you verify that the actual value of `Path.Combine(exeConfigPath, "ClassLibrary1.config")` corresponds to the correct path?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129797/discussion-between-manoj-naik-and-haim770).